# How do I get the current and maximum stack size of a Rust thread?

Tags: rust

In Rust, how do I find out how big the stack of current thread is and what the maximum allowed size for that thread is (by maximum allowed size I mean the size that is usually set via `RUST_MIN_STACK` or the `Builder::stack_size` function). Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Current stack size {:?}", get_current_stack_size());
    println!("Maximum stack size {:?}", get_maximum_stack_size());
}
```

Is there any built-in functionality in Rust?

Comment: Especially "current" stack size is too obscure to be built in.